# how to get string from powershell's 2 line output

Tags: python, powershell

I need to get a string from powershell output. I need to get package name
i.e **prompt-toolkit** and use it in the pipe below

```
> pip list --outdated
Package        Version Latest Type
-------------- ------- ------ -----
prompt-toolkit 1.0.15  2.0.3  wheel
```

> pip list --outdated  | Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_ } |
>   ForEach { pip install -U $_.split(" ")[0] }

UPDATE.
The modified working script

```
    $(
    $exclude = 'virtualenv', 'prompt-toolkit'
    pip list --outdated --format=freeze  | ForEach{ $_.split("=")[0]} | Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_ } | ForEach { pip install -U $_ }                                    
    ) *>&1 >> Python_Modules_Updates_Log.txt
```

Comment: Consider passing the pip list in json format `pip list --outdated --format=json | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: @LotPings, thank you. I have looked into the --format options, and have chosen freeze option. That way i need not use the  select-object -skip 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply try

```
pip list --outdated | select-object -skip 2 | Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_ } | ForEach { pip install -U $_.split(" ")[0] }
```

Comment: The `Where` can't work properly as `$_` still contains all columns. I'd do the split in a calculated property `pip list --outdated | select-object -skip 2 -property @{n='Package';e={$_.split(' ')[0]}} | Where-Object Package -notin $exclude`

Answer (score 0):

To get the Packagenames of the list, you can use the `-ExpandProperty` feature of `Select-Object` and pipe it to the install command:

```
pip list --outdated | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Package | Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_ } | ForEach { pip install -U $_}
```